# adverbial clause acting as adjective

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Consider these sentences, please:

*1) Imagine Robert Redford **when he was a child** - that's what John looks like.*

*2) Imagine Robert Redford **as a child** - that's what John looks like.*

***Question 1***: Can I say that the bold clauses in 1 and 2 are modifying the noun "*Robert Redford*" **adjectivally**?

***Question 2***: Comparing 1 with 2, can we say that "***as***" in *sentence 2* is **not** a preposition, but rather an adverbial conjunction of time? For example:

*Imagine Robert Redford **as he was a child** - that's what John looks like.*

Comment: In theory, the second sentence is ambiguous. It could also mean *imagine Robert Redford as [**if you were**] a child* or *imagine Robert Redford as a child [**would**]*. Most people would not make that interpretation, but it's possible. In that sense, it would be modifying *imagine*. Note that the construction would be similar to *I want you to draw as a child*.

Comment: No. The expressions in bold are, respectively, an adjunct in clause structure and complement of "imagine". As" is a preposition.

Comment: You've asked the same question on at least one other website. Did you not get a satisfactory answer?

Comment: Yes I didn't get a satisfactory answer there

Comment: @BillJ, You said "*The expressions in bold are, respectively, an adjunct in clause structure*"---By "adjunct", do you mean "noun adjunct"?

Comment: No, an adjunct in clause structure.

Comment: Ok. So this "adjunct in clause structure" modifies the noun "Robert Redford." Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and no.

Just because something is a modifier in noun phrase structure does not make it into an adjective. It's just a modifier.

From the Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar p254:

> Modification is a general term. Nouns are typically modified by
> adjectives (strictly speaking, adjective phrases, e.g. ***lovely** weather*),
> prepositional phrases (e.g. *the food **in the fridge***), or relative clauses (e.g. *the house **that was demolished***); adjectives and adverbs
> are modified by adverbs (strictly speaking, adverb phrases, e.g. ***much**
> warmer*, ***very** warmly*); and so on.

And futher, on the subject of 'adjectival', p8:

> adjectival (n. & adj.) Loosely, (a word, phrase, or clause) behaving
> like an adjective (including single-word adjectives); e.g. in a *damp
> cloth*, the word *damp* is an adjectival element.
>
> The term is also used for examples like the following:
>
> *guide* price
>
> the *greenhouse* effect
>
> the man *in the white suit*
>
> an *I’m-all-right-Jack* attitude
>
> Some writers informally use the word adjectival to describe all of the
> italicized strings (or even say that they are adjectives), but this is
> infelicitous, since form and function are being confused: the first
> two examples involve nouns as modifiers; the third example involves a
> prepositional phrase; and the final example has a clause as modifier.

As far as the 'adverbial conjunction' goes - just because two constituents have a similar semantic effect doesn't mean they fall into the same word-class.

It's quite well established that *as* is a preposition in this case and it heads a prepositional phrase that is complement to the verb *imagine* (CaGEL p279).

Comment: "*Just because something is a modifier in noun phrase structure does not make it into an adjective.*"---Do you mean the adverbial clause "when he was a child" modifies the noun "Robert Redford", but we do not call it an adjective?

Comment: Yes, you read correctly. Prepositional phrase _when he was a child_ does modify _Robert Redford_, and is a modifier in the noun phrase _Robert Redford when he was a child_. Modifiers in NP structure come from various categories and should not be called adjectives or 'adjectival' simply because they modify a noun.

Comment: *Prepositional phrase **when he was a child** does modify Robert Redford*----Do you call it a prepositional phrase? To me, it looks more like an adverbial clause of time.